# Битовые операции

Tags: python

000000C0 – шестнадцатеричное число, каждый октет (4 разряда) которого представляют нужные данные. Старшие два разряда седьмого октета представляют последовательность бит, если посчитать последовательно то получим 25-26.

```
cid_h = "000000C0"
(bin(int(cid_h, 16))[2:]).zfill(len(cid_h)*4)
'00000000000000000000000011000000'

[x for x in enumerate(l,start=1) if x[1] == '1']
[(25, '1'), (26, '1')]
```

Вопрос? Как получить последовательность бит? Мой вариант ужасный...

Comment: хм... а можно вопрос переформулировать?

Answer (score 1):

## код

```
number<<2 # сдвиг влево на два бита
number>>3 # сдвиг вправо на три бита
nuber=number and 7 # оставить в числе только первые три бита, остальные обнулить.
```

Стиль вашего кода просто ужасен.

Код нечитаем.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int("000000C0", 16)
getbit = lambda x, i: (x >> i) & 1 # изымаем i-ый бит, считая от младшего к старшему
print(getbit(n, 32-25), getbit(n, 32-26)) # -> 1 1
```

`32-k` используется, чтобы преобразовать 25-26 биты (big-endian -- "тупоконечный" порядок битов) в 32-битной числе, в 7,6 биты (little-endian -- "остроконечный": от младшего бита к старшему).